# How to prove this equality with zeta-function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Consider $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{e^{x}-1}$. I figured that value of this integral is equal to $(n-1)!\zeta(n)$.

How can we show that?? I absolutely surprised.

Comment: And note $\Gamma(s) \zeta(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-2} \frac{x}{e^x-1}dx=\int_0^1  x^{s-2}(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} x^k)dx+\int_1^\infty x^{s-2} \frac{x}{e^x-1}dx$ $=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} \frac{1}{s+k-1}+\int_1^\infty x^{s-2} \frac{x}{e^x-1}dx$ gives the analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometrically expand
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{e^x-1} =\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}} =\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  e^{-jx}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now interchange the order of the integral and sum. Substitute $y=jx$  and then use the definition of the gamma function.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n }{e^x-1} dx  =\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} x^n  e^{-jx} dx =\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{y}{j}\right)^n  e^{-y} \frac{dy}{j} =\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{j^{n+1}} =n! \zeta(n+1).
\end{eqnarray*}